# java: remove cdata tag from xml

Tags: java, regex, xslt, xpath, cdata

xpath is nice for parsing xml files, but its not working for data inside the cdata tag:

```
<![CDATA[ Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>... ]]>
```

My solution: Get the content of the xml first and remove

```
"<![CDATA["  and  "]]>".
```

After that I would run xpath "to reach everything" from the xml file. Is there a better solution? If not, how can I do it with a regular expression?

Comment: removing CDATA may render your xml invalid (and maybe useless for processing purposes)

Comment: Regex and XML DO NOT MIX.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348

Comment: So what would be the solution to get informations like title, description, pubtime and at the same time cdata content from a rss xml file? It's actualle the image link that I need from CDATA.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the CDATA tags there is that everything inside them is **pure text**, nothing which should be interpreted directly as XML. You could write your document fragment in the question alternatively as

```xml
 Some Text &lt;p&gt;more text and tags&lt;/p&gt;...
```

(with a leading and trailing space).

If you really want to interpret this as XML, extract the text from your document, and submit it to an XML parser again.

Comment: I'm curious if you're suggesting something simpler as my proposed answer?

Comment: Not really ... I just said that the problem normally shouldn't exist, as the content in the CDATA area is not meant to be interpreted as XML.

Answer (score 2):

To strip the CDATA and keep the tags as tags, you could use XSLT.

**Given this XML input:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
    <child>Here is some text.</child>
    <child><![CDATA[Here is more text <p>with tags</p>.]]></child>
</root>
```

**Using this XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Will return the following XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <child>Here is some text.</child>
   <child>Here is more text <p>with tags</p>.</child>
</root>
```

(Tested with Saxon HE 9.3.0.5 in oXygen 12.2)

Then you could use xPath to extract the contents of the `p` element:

```
/root/child/p
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to accomplish the same task. I have solved it with two xslt.

Just let me stress that this will only work if the `CDATA` is [well-formed xml](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

To be complete, let me add to your example xml a root element:

```xml
<root>
   <well-formed-content><![CDATA[ Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>]]>
   </well-formed-content>
</root>
```

**Fig 1.- Starting xml**

---

## First step

In the first transformation step, I have wrapped all text nodes in a new introduced xml entity `old_text`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Attribute-nodes and comment-nodes: Pass through without modifying -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Text-nodes: Wrap them in a new node without escaping it. -->
    <!-- (note precondition: CDATA should be valid xml.           -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:element name="old_text">
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Fig 2.- First xslt (wrapping CDATA in "old_text" elements)**

If you apply this transformation to the starting xml this is what you get (I'm not reformatting it to avoid confusion about who does what):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root><old_text>
    </old_text><well-formed-content><old_text> Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>
    </old_text></well-formed-content><old_text>
</old_text></root>
```

**Fig 3.- Transformed xml (first step)**

---

## Second step

You now need to clean-up the introduced `old_text` elements, and re-escape the text that didn't create new nodes:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0"
    encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" />

    <!-- Element-nodes: Process nodes and their children -->
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*|comment()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Attribute-nodes and comment-nodes: Pass through without modifying -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        'Wrapper'-node: remove the wrapper element but process its children.
        With this matcher, the "old_text" is cleaned, but the originally CDATA
        well-formed nodes surface in the resulting xml.
    -->
    <xsl:template match="old_text">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()" />
    </xsl:template>

    <!--
        Text-nodes: Text here comes from original CDATA and must be now
        escaped. Note that the previous rule has extracted all the existing
        nodes in the CDATA. -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="no" />
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Fig 4.- 2nd xslt (cleaned-up artificially-introduced elements)**

---

## Result

This is the final result, with the nodes that originally where in CDATA expanded in your new xml file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root>
    <well-formed-content> Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>
    </well-formed-content>
</root>
```

**Fig 5.- Final xml**

---

## Caveat

If your CDATA contains html character entities not supported in xml (take a look for examples at this [wikipedia article about character entities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)), you need to add those references to your intermediate xml. Let me show this with an example:

```xml
<root>
    <well-formed-content>
        <![CDATA[ Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>,
        now with a non-breaking-space before the stop:&nbsp;.]]>
    </well-formed-content>
</root>
```

**Fig 6.- Added character entity `&nbsp;` to xml in Fig 1**

The original xslt from **Fig 2** will convert the xml into this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root><old_text>
    </old_text><well-formed-content><old_text>
        Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>,
        now with a non-breaking-space before the stop:&nbsp;.
    </old_text></well-formed-content><old_text>
</old_text></root>
```

**Fig 7.- Result of a first try to convert the xml in Fig 6 (Not well-formed!)**

The problem with this file is that it is not well-formed, and thus, cannot be further processed with a XSLT-processor:

```
The entity "nbsp" was referenced, but not declared.
XML checking finished.
```

**Fig 8.- Result of the well-formedness checking for the xml in Fig 7**

This workaround does the trick (the `match="/"` template adds the `&nbsp;` entity):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" version="1.0"
                encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" />

    <!-- Add an html entity to the xml character entities declaration. -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[<!DOCTYPE root
[
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>
]]>
        </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()|@*|comment()|processing-instruction()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Attribute-nodes and comment-nodes: Pass through without modifying -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|comment()|processing-instruction()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Text-nodes: Wrap them in a new node without escaping it. -->
    <!-- (note precondition: CDATA should be valid xml.           -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:element name="old_text">
            <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Fig 9.- The xslt creates the entity declaration**

Now, after applying this xslt to the **Fig 6** source xml, this is the intermediate xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><!DOCTYPE root
[
    <!ENTITY nbsp "&#160;">
]>

        <root><old_text>
    </old_text><well-formed-content><old_text>
        Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>,
        now with a non-breaking-space before the stop:&nbsp;.
    </old_text></well-formed-content><old_text>
</old_text></root>
```

**Fig 10.- Intermediate xml (xml from Fig 3 plus entity declaration)**

You can use the xslt transformation from **Fig 4** to produce the final xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><root>
    <well-formed-content>
        Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>,
        now with a non-breaking-space before the stop: .
    </well-formed-content>
</root>
```

**Fig 11.- Final xml with html entites converted to UTF-8**

---

#### Notes

For these examples I have used NetBeans 7.1.2 built-in XSLT processor (`com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl - default JRE XSLT processor`)

*Disclaimer: I'm not an XML expert. I have the feeling that this should be even easier...*

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely remove the cdata from xml by using the regex to remove the desired content from your xml.

for example:

```
String s = "<sn><![CDATA[poctest]]></sn>";
s = s.replaceAll("!\\[CDATA", "");
s = s.replaceAll("]]", "");
s = s.replaceAll("\\[", "");
```

Result will be:

```
<sn><poctest></sn>
```

Please check,if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static removeCDATA (String text) {
    String resultString = "";
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?<!(<!\\[CDATA\\[))|((.*)\\w+\\W)");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(text);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        resultString += regexMatcher.group();
    }
    return resultString;
}
```

When I call this method with your test input `<![CDATA[ Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>... ]]>` method return `Some Text <p>more text and tags</p>`

But I think this method without regular expressions will be more reliable. Something like this:

```
public static removeCDATA (String text) {
    s = s.trim();
    if (s.startsWith("<![CDATA[")) {
        s = s.substring(9);
        int i = s.indexOf("]]>");
        if (i == -1) throw new IllegalStateException("argument starts with <![CDATA[ but cannot find pairing ]]>");
        s = s.substring(0, i);
    }
    return s;
}
```