# Remove <!CDATA[ X ]]> from XML in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, cdata

I have xml webservice response with CDATA in the response :

```
 <![CDATA[
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ReturnCode>0</ReturnCode>
        <ReturnDescription>SUCCESS</ReturnDescription>
    </Response>]]>
```

I need to remove what is between the opening `<!CDATA[` and closing `]]>` and keep the xml only.

I have searched for a solution on many forums but i can't find useful answer .

Comment: this might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836730/java-remove-cdata-tag-from-xml

Comment: Please edit your question to include your full source code on how you try to solve your problem? What are you trying to do with this `<!CDATA[` stuff and why are you doing it manually? What XML parser are you using and how does having `<!CDATA[` stuff affect you (because it shouldn't)?